# Upper bound of $(\log_2 n)^{\log_2 n}$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I'm trying to prove that $2^n$ is an upper bound for $(\log_2 n)^{\log_2 n}$.

Looking at the graph of these two functions it seems that $(\log_2 n)^{\log_2 n}=\mathrm{O}(2^n)$ but I couldn't prove it rigorously.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Nightflight What you are showing is $\log_2(m)^{\log_2(m)} \ge m$...

Comment: Another expression for $\log_2(n)^{\log_2(n)}$ is $2^{\log_2(n)\cdot\log_2(\log_2(n))}$ so you have to compare, let say $n$ and $\log_2(n)^2$.

Comment: @zwim There's another $\log_2(n)$ in the exponent there, isn't there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll calculate $A={\log n}^{\log n}$, which is absolutely bigger than ${\log_2n}^{\log_2n}$(when $n>2$), and $B=e^{\frac n4}$, absolutely smaller than $2^n$.

I'll take logarithm, then $\log A=\log n\cdot\log\log n<(\log n)^2$(with sufficiently large n), and $\log B=\frac n4=(\frac {\sqrt n}2)^2$.

And by L'Hospital's rule, that is valid:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\frac{\sqrt n}2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2\log n}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac2n}{\frac1{2\sqrt n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac4{\sqrt n}=0
$$

It means, $\log n<\frac{\sqrt n}2$ is valid with sufficiently large $n$. So...

$$
{\log_2n}^{\log_2n}<A=e^{\log A}<e^{(\log n)^2}<e^{\frac n4}=B<2^n
$$